# iPhone plays podcasts in seemingly random order

Tags: iphone, ipod, podcasts

Does anyone know why my iPhone has (suddenly) started playing podcasts in seemingly random order? I want podcasts to be played in the order they were downloaded (in iTunes), chronologically.

However, when I start listening to a podcast with more than two entries, the second entry iPhone plays is seldom the second in chronological order, but some seemingly random entry. Why is this and how can I fix it?

**Update**: Here's how the Music application's interface looks like on my iPhone:

[image]

I can't see a shuffle icon anywhere. The icon on the lower right hand side is the airplay icon. Here's a screenshot after tapping the "album art":

[image]

Here's a screenshot from while playing music:

[image]

There I can see a shuffle icon (finally), but it's not enabled (blue).

Comment: How are you listening? Are you using a playlist or just through the podcast interface on the iPhone?

Comment: have you discovered a possible reason for their order? release date, alphabetical?

Comment: @MikeWills, I'm using the podcast interface.

Comment: @GraemeHutchison, the order seems to be completely random. I have podcasts where each episode is named "Name - yyyymmdd" which would be played in chronological order if they had been played alphabetically, but they aren't.

Answer (score 2):

Did you have shuffle on while listening to music? If you did, the podcasts will also be shuffled.

Comment: Where do I find this setting? Is it in iTunes or somewhere on my iPhone? Inside the Music application or within Settings?

Comment: The Music application on your phone. Tap the screen so the scrubber controls come up, and there is a shuffle icon along the right side.

Comment: I've updated the question with an image of how the Music app looks like. I can't see any shuffle icon. :-/

Comment: @asbjornu: Tap the screen (the album artwork) to bring up the scrubber pane. The shuffle icon is on the right side of the scrubber pane.

Comment: I added another screenshot to my question. I still see no shuffle icon.

Comment: @asbjornu: You have to be playing music to see the shuffle icon.

Comment: I agree with @mipadi.  The 1X feature in your screenshot appears only if a podcast is playing.  Back out of the podcast and navigate to albums>all songs to play a song.  when a song is playing, you'll see controls to turn shuttle off and on or play a song in a loop.

Comment: @bg2011, I've added another screenshot from while playing music. While I can finally see a shuffle icon now, it's not enabled (blue).

Answer (score 0):

I usually do a playlist and sort it based on whatever criteria I want. The order usually sticks well then.

**Update**: I use a smart playlist. Kind = Podcast and playcount = 0. From there you sort the playlist based on how you want it sorted. I then added rules to exclude from the podiobooks playlist and the music podcast playlist.

I had added others one for music and one for podiobooks. They where create by Kind = podcast and album = podcast name. I added one album = for each podcast in the list. I didn't add many after I had it setup so I didn't edit those much.

The main list was then dynamically updated based on these other two lists. Simple and maintenance free.

Comment: I subscribe to so many podcasts that this would be a maintenance nightmare. I'd like to find a solution that works by default, if possible.

Comment: I used to use the iTunes podcasts. I have 5 playlists and subscribed to about 70 podcasts. I had one playlist for podiobooks, one for music podcasts, one for video, and one for only the short podcasts. I'll clarify how I do that.